# Using #urls in jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, e-commerce

I've managed to confuse myself here. Basically I am using jQuery to turn a div into a link with;

```
$('.product').click(function() {
window.open('product.php','jav');
});
```

This works fine but I am using a .php/MySQL database and I want to be able to pass the product ID into the url so it goes to `/product.php#$id`. Normally I'd just use `<a>` tags in my php code but using the Javascript method I can't plug in the PHP variable to the URL.

Probably not making a lot of sense but it's been a long day, happy to answer any questions if it's a little difficult to make out what I'm asking for here.

Comment: Do you have product id as with `.product` element? i.e. the `id`?

Comment: Not sure what you mean there. Here's the PHP code for the .product element.
    `<li class='product' id='$id'>`
    `<h2>$title</h2>`
    `<img src='_images/$img.png' />`
    `</li>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emit the product ID as part of the `div`'s markup. Here I've shown two options: a `data-` attribute and the contents of the `div`. I'd prefer the data- attribute since your content is probably already defined. You can see all that is below on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XXzjE/5/).

```
<div class="product" data-id="42">42</div>
```

Now access it when building your URL:

```
$('.product').click(function() {
    //window.open('product.php','jav');

    var id = $(this).data('id'); // Alternatively use .attr('data-id')
    alert('product.php#' + id); 

    var text = $(this).text();
    alert('product.php#' + text);
});
```

Comment: Got it using this. Thanks a lot, been a long day lol

`$('.product').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).data('id'); 
    window.open('product.php#' + id); 
});`

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need to have the id somewhere in your markup. If `.product` are `<a>`, you can assign to each one the complete url, like:

`<a href="product.php?id=333">`

So, in your jquery code:

```
$('.product').click(function() {
     window.open($(this).attr('href'),'jav');
     return false;
});
```

(Not tested)

ADDED:
Missing `return false;`

This will also works if user has js disabled, as it will navigate to the right page instead of opening it as popup.

Answer (score 0):

If you put the id in a custom attribute you can pull it on the click event:

For example:

```
<div class=".product" urlid="someproductid"></div>
```

then later in your click event handler you can use jQuery's attr method to get the value.